# apache httpclient syncronized execution

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I want to make a test application in Java, what is testing what is happening when I do 2 post/put request at the same time to the same URI. I have written the putter and poster functions, I made a runnable class what generate test files, and run the functions in separated threads, at the same time. The problem is when I'm uploading a file what is bigger then 1Mb the network delay is ruin my measure. So I want to end the 2 execution very close.

I am using the [Apache httpclient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) opensource library I try to searching in the source, but I'm not so good in reverse engineering. I think synchronizing the entry classes will not work. I tried to warp out the DefaultRequestDirector, but it is dead end to me too, because I'm not an expert in http protocols, and I don't understand what those functions do and why (but mostly why).

Can somebody tell me what classes and functions I need to modify if I want to leave open the uploading stream (or holding back the last pocket) until the other thread is reach the same point?

Comment: I'm curious why you want to try this? Supposing your servlets/handlers are threadsafe (most common gotche is using instance variables...) there should be problems.

Comment: I try to see on some services how they handle this situation. e.g. what the dropbox do when 2 file arraives at the same time to the same location with the same name.

Comment: Surely you can test that with a mocking framework instead of going the full HTTP route?